# ¿Por qué me sale error de variable indefinida?

Tags: php

¿Por qué me sale error de variable indefinida?

```
<?php

extract($_REQUEST);
require "conexion.php";
$objconexion=conectarse();
$sql="select * from usuarios where login='$_REQUEST[login]' and contraseña='$_REQUEST[contraseña]'";
$resultado=$objconexion->query($sql);
$es=$resultado->nuw_rows;
if($es==1)
{
  $usuarios=$resultado->fetch_object();
  $_SESSION['user']=$usuarios->login;
  header("location:vistaPrincipal.php");
}else
{
  header("location:index.php?x=1");
}
 ?>
```

La otra parte del código es:

```
 <?php
    if($x==1)
      echo "<br>Usuario no registrado con los datos ingresado. Vuelva a intentar.";
    if ($x==2)
      echo "<br>Inicia sesión para ingresar a la aplicación.";

    if ($x==3)
      echo "<br>El usuario ha cerrado sesión";
     ?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: me dice que la variable x es indefinida

Comment: @Lixus es que le estoy diciendo que cuando en el formulario se conecte un usuario inexistente me lance la misma pagina pero con un mensaje que diga que no existe. fijate que en la sentencia location le doy un valor a x a saber 1.

Comment: $es=$resultado->nuw_rows;
if($es==1)
{
  $usuarios=$resultado->fetch_object();
  $_SESSION['user']=$usuarios->login;
  header("location:vistaPrincipal.php");
}else
{
  header("location:index.php?x=1");
}
 ?>

Answer (score 1):

Esto es porque tu variable `$x` no ha sido inicializada dentro de tu bloque de PHP. No confundas la variable `GET` `x` que envías desde la URL:`index.php?x=1` en tu función `location` contra tu otra variable de nombre `$x`, ya que son distintas.

Para acceder al valor de la variable `x` que mandaste desde la URL y asignarlo a tu variable `$x` tienes que usar la siguiente línea:

```
$x = $_GET['x'];
```

Así ya tu variable tendrá el valor asignado y podrás hacer las comparaciones en el resto de tu bloque de código.